# Python Requests Exceptions

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

When i  try to post a request am getting this error and i just try to add an exception , but exception cannot handle it

```
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.examplewebsite.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))
```

i have tried this

```
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as C:
    print "Failed"
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
    print "Failed"
```

But still the same Error

any way to solve it ?

Edit :

```
def job(lk):
    try:
        session = requests.session()

        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'}
        r = session.get("https://www.example.com/login/")
        post = session.post('https://www.example.com', data={"log": "name",
                                                                       "pwd": "name",},
                                                                        headers=headers)
        rGet = session.get('https://www.example.com')


    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as C:
        print "Failed 2"
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        print "Failed 3"
```

Comment: Could you show a little more of your code please? Mostly the part related to the try/catch, it could help, thank you!

Comment: Code added in question
Please check

Comment: @GreyByte right now you catch exception during _creating (defining) a function_. If you want to catch exceptions during _execution of a function_, try/except blocks should be defined _within_ function body.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this -

```
try:
    res = requests.get(adress,timeout=30)
except requests.ConnectionError as e:
    print("OOPS!! Connection Error. Make sure you are connected to Internet. Technical Details given below.\n")
    print(str(e))            
except requests.Timeout as e:
    print("OOPS!! Timeout Error")
    print(str(e))
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print("OOPS!! General Error")
    print(str(e))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Someone closed the program")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your try/except block is not at the right place, it has to be **within** the function:

```
def job(lk):
    session = requests.session()
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'}
    try:

        r = session.get("https://www.example.com/login/")
        post = session.post(
            'https://www.example.com', 
            data={"log": "name", "pwd": "name",},                                                                 
            headers=headers
            )
        rGet = session.get('https://www.example.com')


    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as C:
        print "Failed 2"
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        print "Failed 3"
```

Also note that your current exception handling will not be very usefull for troubleshooting - you don't have the exact exception, the full traceback, and you don't even know which of the three requests failed - but I assume this is just placeholder code ATM.

Comment: yes , it is within the function
just an error while posting here

Comment: @GreyByte if you hope to get any help please post the right code and the complete exception message, traceback etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `try catch` block should be inside the function.

```
def job(lk):
    try:
        session = requests.session()

        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'}
        r = session.get("https://www.example.com/login/")
        post = session.post('https://www.example.com', data={"log": "name",
                                                                       "pwd": "name",},
                                                                        headers=headers)
        rGet = session.get('https://www.example.com')


    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Failed 2")
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        print("Failed 3")
```

Comment: try/catch is inside the function
Just an error while pasting here

Answer (score 0):

As Bruno said, the try/except should be inside the function (or wrapped around the code that calls the function).

The reason is that the exception happens when the function is called and running; whereas your try/except block as it is only catches errors raised **while declaring the function**, not while it is running.

If you do not understand the difference, you should try to understand better how functions work in the book/documentation/course you use to learn Python.

Comment: The try/catch is inside the function 
Its just an error while posting here

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you aren't getting the exception you think you are getting. Run your code with a generic `except` to determine exactly what type of exception is being raised:

```
except Exception as exc:
    print(type(exc), str(exc))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the exception thrown at you is a newConnectionError, start by catching this (for better exception handling)

Second, in the exception it tells you that it exceeded the max retries with url, are username, password correct?, and are the parameters for the server you are trying to connect to "log": "name""pwd": "name"

Code for better exception handling:

```
def job(lk):
    try:
        session = requests.session()

        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'}
        r = session.get("https://www.example.com/login/")
        post = session.post('https://www.example.com', data={"log": "name",
                                                                   "pwd": "name",},
                                                                    headers=headers)
        rGet = session.get('https://www.example.com')

    except NewConnectionError as nCE:
        print f"failed 1 - NewConnection error: {nCE}"

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as C:
        print "Failed 2"

    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        print "Failed 3"except NewConnectionError:
```